# Select a button without calling click

Tags: unity

i have a grid layout group containing buttons. My game must be playable with a joystick and so I have to navigate the buttons using horizontal/vertical input.

My problem right now is when the layout group first becomes visible. Once I click on a button (with my mouse), it becomes "selected" and I can navigate through the layout group with my keyboard and 'click' with spacebar. This functionality is all fine, *except* for the need to click the button with a mouse to set the first selection.

I've tried both of the following:

```
void buttonClicked() {
    Debug.Log("clicked");
}

void Start () {
  // this button is actually instantiated from a prefab,
  // not shown here
  Button btn = inventorySlot.button;

  btn.onClick.AddListener(buttonClicked);

  # attempt 1
  btn.Select();

  # attempt 2
  eventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(
    btn.gameObject,
    new BaseEventData(eventSystem)
  );
}
```

both these commands *do* select the button, but they also inadvertently call the `onClick`, and the button is clearly being clicked because it changes color (I have configured this through button opts in the inspector).

My question is - how can I "select" the button without clicking it?

I perhaps should also note, I am populating the layout group with buttons at runtime. Each button is intantiated from a prefab in `Start()` (not showing that here). I only add the event listeners and try to select the button after it's already added to actual game objects in my scene.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the issue was that I call `btn.Select()` before the menu is actually open, and space is *also* the command to show the menu. So basically I need to put the `btn.Select()` *after* the menu is visible.